# SignalR peer to peer (js to js) communcation

Tags: javascript, signalr, p2p

I'd like to support a LANClient to LANClient connection between two or more JS clients. I plan to use a permanent external C# server to establish the local connection (identify if two clients are on the same LAN and exchange their local net addresses).

Is there any support for this in SignalR? Is it possible to host a hub server on JS? Is there any support for direct client to client communication?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, taken from http://signalr.net/

> ## What is ASP.NET SignalR
>
> ASP.NET SignalR is a new library for ASP.NET developers that makes it incredibly simple to add real-time web functionality to your applications. What is "real-time web" functionality? **It's the ability to have your server-side code push content to the connected clients** as it happens, in real-time.
>
> You may have heard of WebSockets, a new HTML5 API that enables bi-directional communication **between the browser and server**. SignalR will use WebSockets under the covers when it's available, and gracefully fallback to other techniques and technologies when it isn't, while your application code stays the same.
>
> SignalR also provides a very simple, high-level API for doing **server to client** RPC (call JavaScript functions in your clients' browsers from server-side .NET code) in your ASP.NET application, as well as adding useful hooks for connection management, e.g. connect/disconnect events, grouping connections, authorization.

So, to communicate the clients using SignalR, you should use a SignalR HUB.

Comment: Fair enough, thank you!For anyone in the future, this is possible using WebRTC or PeerJS (working on WebRTC).